# define path that contains variable (php)

Tags: php, variables, constants

i am working on a image slide show

```
$article = "This is the title of the slide show images";
```

now tying to define the path

```
// set the absolute path to the directory containing the images
define ("IMGDIR", "./pathsubdir/$article/");
```

and tried

```
define ('IMGDIR', '/articles/" . $article . "/');
```

does not work  ( both above)

```
define ('IMGDIR', '/articles/"This is the title of the slide show images"/');
```

That works ^

but how can i put it a variable so it works? as $article is a dynmaic value

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
define ('IMGDIR', '/articles/' . $article . '/');
```

if you need double quotes in article

```
define ('IMGDIR', '/articles/"' . $article . '"/');
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you............ i di try that but i didnt have ".." for current directory when i tried it. but now that you said it was right i added the .. and itworked thanks